# Applying formatting to a big range

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to use the Excel Interop C# libraries to copy cell formatting from one cell to a range of other cells. To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
var excelWrapper = new Application();
excelWrapper.DisplayAlerts = false;

var workBook = excelWrapper.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\myFile.xlsx");
Worksheet ws = workBook.Sheets[1] as Worksheet;
Range formatSource = ws.Cells[8, 1] as Range; //cell containing formatting that I want to apply
Range startCell = ws.Cells[9, 1] as Range; //first cell to format
Range endCell = ws.Cells[300, 1] as Range; //last cell to format
Range formatTarget = ws.Range[startCell, endCell];

//Copy formatting from source cell to destination range
formatSource.Copy();
formatTarget.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
```

As you can see, I'm applying the format from cell `[8,1]` to the entire range `[9,1] -> [300,1]`.

The problem I'm having is that this only applies the formatting to the first ~80 or so cells, after that the formatting is not applied. In particular, the formatting stops after row 91, so it is only applied to the first 84 of the 291 cells in the range.

I don't understand why the formatting is not applied to the entire range I selected, but only to the first 84 cells. What am I missing here? Note that the range I'm applying the style to starts empty (I write the data only after setting the formatting), so it isn't a problem derived from the data in the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out: the excel file **looked** empty, but actually it contained a table that stopped at row 91. Evidently, when you paste a format to a range that is "hybrid" (half inside table and half normal cells) the format only gets applied to the portion inside the table.